# AgGrid StatusBar Rendering Timeout (not created within 1000ms)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using AgGrid w/ the Server Side Row Model. I wanted the status bar to display the number of rows. Since the built-in row count component only works with the Client Side Row Model, I wrote a custom component to do it (see below).

The below status bar component works - when it loads. However, sometimes ag-grid will fail to load the component and will instead display the following error in the console:

`index.js:1350 AG Grid: React Component 'TotalRowCountComponent' not created within 1000ms`

Since the component is very light-weight and should quickly render, I believe this is a problem with the AgGrid library. I'm using version 27 currently.

If anyone knows how to get around this issue please advise. I'd very much like a working status bar...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IStatusPanelParams } from "ag-grid-enterprise";
import { ModelUpdatedEvent } from "ag-grid-community";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 8px 0px; 
  margin: 0px 4px;
`;

const Label = styled.label`
`;

const Value = styled.span`
  color: var(--ag-foreground-color, #000);
`;

export const TotalRowCountComponent = (params: IStatusPanelParams) => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(-1);
  
  const onModelUpdated = (e: ModelUpdatedEvent) => {
    setCount(e.api.getDisplayedRowCount());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    params.api.addEventListener('modelUpdated', onModelUpdated);
    return () => {
      params.api.removeEventListener('modelUpdated', onModelUpdated);
    }
  }, [params?.api])

  if(count < 0) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Label>Rows:</Label>
      &nbsp;
      <Value>{count}</Value>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted my functional React component to a class component and - for w/e reason - AgGrid now consistently loads my status bar without error...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IStatusPanelParams } from "ag-grid-enterprise";
import { FirstDataRenderedEvent, GridApi, GridReadyEvent, ModelUpdatedEvent } from "ag-grid-community";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 8px 0px; 
  margin: 0px 4px;
`;

const Label = styled.label`
`;

const Value = styled.span`
  color: var(--ag-foreground-color, #000);
`;

interface TotalRowCountComponentState {
  count?: number;
  params: IStatusPanelParams;
}

export class TotalRowCountComponent extends React.Component<IStatusPanelParams, TotalRowCountComponentState> {

  constructor(params: IStatusPanelParams) {
    super(params);
    this.state = {
      params: params
    };
    this.onModelUpdated = this.onModelUpdated.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.params.api.addEventListener('modelUpdated', this.onModelUpdated);
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.params.api.getDisplayedRowCount()
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.params.api.removeEventListener('modelUpdated', this.onModelUpdated);
  }

  onModelUpdated(e: ModelUpdatedEvent) {
    this.setState({
      count: e.api.getDisplayedRowCount()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Label>Rows:</Label>
        &nbsp;
        <Value>{this.state.count || 0}</Value>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```